# Has Google been Hacked or do I have a Virus/Spy/Trojan?

Tags: google-search

Since Yesterday I think, titles in my Google Search results are displayed Bold unless it's due to the Font chosen...

Moreover, for the 1st time since a long time (don't even know if it ever happened to me?) while not finding good results for my query, I displays porn websites as a proposal.

The query : `jitsi close2 postMessage`

The result : [image: Google Hacked?]

Only the 1st result is linked to jitsi, 5 others are sex related as 2 and 3 in screenshot.

Jitsi is a videoconferencing App, Close2 is the step when participants hangout And postMessage is JavaScript to communicate between iframe and container (at least in my case).

Do you think it could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Has Google been Hacked or do I have a Virus/Spy/Trojan?"*

**None of the above has happened. Relax :)**

Here is why:

> *"...titles in my Google Search results are displayed Bold unless it's due to the Font chosen..."*

Just the new Google interface.

> *"...while not finding good results for my query, I displays porn websites as a proposal"*

As you can read on the notice...

> It looks like there aren't many great matches for your search Tip: Try
> using words that might appear on the page you’re looking for. For
> example, "cake recipes" instead of "how to make a cake." Need help?
> Take a look at other tips for searching on Google.

Google explains why you get those results.
**To avoid those explicit results, change your settings and block them**.

[image]